# Probability Assimilation using python

Tags: python

I am trying to get some probability by simulating a game (assimilation) using python.

A and B play a game where they take turns to throw a coin (A starts first), and the first one to throw a head wins. But their coins are biased! A's coin has a 1 in 5 chance of coming up heads, and B's coin has a 1 in 3 chance of coming up heads.

The code should simulate it and answer this question: What is the probability of A winning if he goes first?

By solving through mathematically, I came to this solution: `3/7`.

This is what I've done so far, but it doesn't give me the expected number.

```
import numpy as np

def P1_win_prob_weighted_coin_game(num_games, prob_heads=.5): 
  player_one_wins = 0 
  for n in range(0,num_games): 
    num_flips = 0 
    win = 0
    while win == 0: 
      turn = np.random.uniform(0,1) 
      num_flips += 1 
      if turn <= prob_heads: 
        if num_flips % 2 != 0: 
          player_one_wins += 1 
        win += 1 
  return float(player_one_wins)/float(num_games)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please give more details? Who starts? Is it a simulation of the problem? Or you just want to calculate mathematically this probability? One or two examples of plays and expected results would be great!

Comment: Hey Alan, A starts at first. I want to create a simulation. I have done it mathematically. 

What is the probability of A winning if he goes first?
By solving through mathematically, I came to this solution 3/7. I want to create simulation in python

Comment: _but it doesn't work_ What does that mean, exactly? What is your question?

Comment: It didn't give me what I was expecting. I was expecting 3/7 outcome but it is not

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

First, define a function that plays one game and tells me who the winner was.

```
def get_winner(prob_to_win=[1/5, 1/3]):
    ''' Tells who the winner was.
    Params:
        prob_to_win is a list with the probabilites of each player to win
    Returns:
        the index of the player who won (based on prob_to_win)
    '''
    number_of_players = len(prob_to_win)
    while True:
        for player in range(number_of_players):
            coin_flip = np.random.uniform()
            if coin_flip <= prob_to_win[player]:
                return player
```

Next, define the names, probabilites and number of games to play (observeations)

```
player_names = ['A', 'B']
player_probs = [1/5, 1/3]
number_of_games = 500000
```

Let the games begin! (Note: for more verbosity, you can uncomment the print line)

```
player_win_count = [0, 0]
for i in range(number_of_games):
    winner = get_winner(player_probs)
    player_win_count[winner] += 1
    # print(f'The winner was {player_names[winner]} ({player_win_count[winner]} wins so far)')
```

Finally, get and display the results.

```
for (player, wins) in zip(player_names, player_win_count):
    chances = wins/number_of_games
    print(f'Statistics (with {number_of_games} observations) tell that player {player} has {chances} chances to win against others')
```

Outputs:

```
Statistics (with 500000 observations) tell that player A has 0.427982 chances to win against others
Statistics (with 500000 observations) tell that player B has 0.572018 chances to win against others
```

Which is very close to the probability that you calculated `3/7`.

Hope it helps! This was fun :)

Comment: @SushilPathak Does this answer your question?